# "He shot it" versus "he shot at it"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is there a difference between these two, or is only one correct?

> I shoot him. I shoot at him. She will shoot you. She will shoot at you.

How about these two?

> The plane shot missiles at the base.

versus

> The plane shot the base at its weapons bunker.

Comment: If he shot it, he hit it. If he shot *at* it, maybe not.

Answer (score 4):

*He shot it* explicitly states that he shot it (the bullet pierced the target). It also could mean that he fired a gun if *it* is representing a firearm.

```
He shot (fired) the gun (it).
```

*He shot at it* only has one meaning; it means that the gun was aimed and fired at a target. It doesn't give any indication of whether the target was hit or not.
The difference is subtle, but they mean different things. You would definitely say *shot at it* if he missed.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one. Both of them are correct grammatically, but the meaning slightly differs.

`I shoot him.`, suggests a more definite outcome of the shot, that it hits the object (in this case a person, *he*). While, `I shot at him`, says nothing about whether the shot hit or missed, it just tells us that the subject (in this case, *I*) aimed to shoot at the object and fired.

In the second one, Only `The plane shot missiles at the base.` seems to be grammatically correct.

I think that this would be more appropriate. "The plane shot *missiles* at the weapons bunker on the base." or "The plane *bombed* the weapons bunker on the base.".

Comment: So, for a marksman, there is no difference between _shot_ and _shot at_ :^)

Comment: Yes - a better pair of sentences to contrast would be _The archer shot at the weakest point of the dragon_ and _The archer shot the dragon at its weakest point_.

Comment: @J.R. I would disagree, but I kinda need to make sure, you aren't one. :D

Comment: @EdwinAshworth crystal clear contrast.

Comment: @J.R. There is a split-second difference - or a bigger one if the target is using a force-field projectile deflector.

Comment: Do you mean that "I shot the disk" is confusing whether the disk is the target, or the projectile?

Comment: @williamC Yes, it might be taken as if the disk is the target until some more information is available(usually provided in the context of the sentence). The context would help clear up that it might even be the projectile.

Comment: @William C _Shoot_ can be intransitive ('Do you shoot?'), take an at-phrase ('He shot at the deer'), take a DO referencing the thing etc hit ('I shot the sheriff') or take a DO referencing the type of ammunition / projectile (He's shooting blanks').

Comment: *I shoot him* is a strange mixture of tense and semantics.  In the present tense at the moment of shooting, it is not known whether the shot will hit or not, so using "shoot" is not recommended.  "I shoot at something" in the present tense turns into either "I shot something" or "I shot at something"  but "I shoot something" is not idiomatic unless one is talking about what one shoots categorically-  *I shoot elk,* *Well I shoot bear*

Comment: @Jim - that's not confined to the verb 'shoot'. The present simple is rarely used alone except to show habitual practice: I snore. I walk often. ?*I solve this problem. I hunt / fish / shoot. ?I prod / shoot / (photograph) / thump him. - these latter use verbs having, unless context decrees otherwise, punctual (moment-in-time) aspect, and don't work for habitual situations.